xz print crc checksum
I have two files, of several gigabytes in size, which have been compressed with xz. I suspect the original files before compression are identical, but they've been compressed with different xz options so the compressed files are different.
How can I verify that the files are identical without uncompressing them? As they're so large I would rather not uncompress them if I don't have to.
I know that xz stores a CRC checksum, so I thought it should be easy enough: just print and compare the CRC checksums of each file. However the xz -l (and xz -l -v) command just lists the checksum as type "CRC64" instead of what the actual checksum is.

xz -lvv will show the checksum of the content in the CheckVal column.
> echo foo > test
> xz --fast -kf test
> md5sum test.xz
73f4e719ee8a19d7afa90939e6340e0c  test.xz
> xz -lvv test.xz
test.xz (1/1)
...
  Blocks:
    Stream     Block      CompOffset    UncompOffset       TotalSize      UncompSize  Ratio  Check      CheckVal          Header  Flags        CompSize    MemUsage  Filters
         1         1              12               0              32               4  8.000  CRC64      f29c31305aacd7ff      16  cu                  8       1 MiB  --lzma2=dict=256KiB
...
> xz --best -kf test
> md5sum test.xz
fc821047713f85563b66cd1dc64b611b  test.xz
> xz -lvv test.xz
test.xz (1/1)
...
  Blocks:
    Stream     Block      CompOffset    UncompOffset       TotalSize      UncompSize  Ratio  Check      CheckVal          Header  Flags        CompSize    MemUsage  Filters
         1         1              12               0              36               4  9.000  CRC64      f29c31305aacd7ff      20  cu                  8      65 MiB  --lzma2=dict=64MiB
...


Are you concerned about decompression time/performance, or about storing the decompressed files?
You can avoid storing the files by using
xzcat file1 | sha256sum
xzcat file2 | sha256sum

and comparing the results.
Alternatively, with enough verbosity (xz -vvl file1), you get the CRC64 value. Since xz allows using different checksum algorithms, it is possible that your archives have been created with different algorithms, in which case this won't help.
If your concern is about decompression time, I'd assume that waiting for an answer on StackExchange takes a bit more time...
